# Save NSDate to CoreData

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsdate, setvalue

i want to save NSDate from XML to coreData.
I dont know how to set the Value for NSDate. Can someone give me little help?
My Entity attribute is NSDate. Or should it be a String and Save the Date as String??

```
[Sets setValue:[TBXML textForElement:xmlDate] forKey:@"beginDate"];
```

Thanks for any response and help,
brush51

Comment: Saving dates as strings is going to leave you in a world of hurt. Leave dates as NSDates and transform them into their readable formats, whether as NSStrings, NSCalendar dates, date components. You get so much for free just by leaving a date as a date.

Comment: Thanks alot for your Help. i have combined the code, to get it in one line(just to setValue) :  **[Sets setValue:[myXMLdateReader dateFromString:[TBXML textForElement:xmlDate]] forKey:@"beginDate"];**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whether you are intentionally obfuscating or not, you don't say it, so I'm going to guess that:

- `[TBXML textForElement:xmlDate]` returns an NSString
- `beginDate` is a Date property of entity `Sets`

In which case your code is obviously incorrect: you must pass an instance of `NSDate` to `setValue:forKey:`. Your code would look like:

```
NSDateFormatter *myXMLdateReader = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[myXMLdateReader setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"]; // for example
NSDate *itsDate = [myXMLdateReader dateFromString:[TBXML textForElement:xmlDate]];
[myXMLdateReader release];
[Sets setValue:itsDate forKey:@"beginDate"];
```

Answer (score 3):

It is no problem to add `NSDate` to `CoreData`. All you need to do is to convert `NSString` from XML file to `NSDate` object. For converting `NSString` **<->** `NSDate` you can use `NSDateFormatter` class. In example below you can see how I do this:

```
NSDateFormatter *parseFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[parseFormatter setLocale:[[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"US"] autorelease]];
[parseFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"];
NSString *dateString = @"Mon, 02 May 2011 21:12:56 +0000";
NSDate *dateToAdd = [parser.parseFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

You can set needful date format and use this code in your project.